# Define generic method invoker - typescript issue

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to write a generic method that execute a function on list of instances:

```
    private exec<Method extends keyof Klass>(
        method: Method,
        ...params: Parameters<Klass[Method]>
    ) {
        this.listeners.map((listener) => listener[method](...params));
    }
```

I got typescript error on `...params`:

```
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0 or more.
```

(each method of Klass accepts between 0-2 parameters).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attempt to invoke the method as `listener[method](...params)`, it would lose the track of `this`. To avoid this, you can use `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply`, something along these lines:

```
this.listeners.map((l) => (l[method] as (...ps: Parameters<Klass[Method]>) => void).apply(l, params))
```

Complete example:

```
class Klass {
    constructor(private readonly v: number) { }
    foo(a: string) { console.log("foo", this.v, a) }
    bar(n: number) { console.log("bar", this.v, n) }
}

const listeners = [
    new Klass(42),
    new Klass(58)
]

function exec<Method extends keyof Klass>(
    method: Method,
    ...params: Parameters<Klass[Method]>
) {
    listeners.map((listener) =>
        (listener[method] as (...ps: Parameters<Klass[Method]>) => void).apply(listener, params));
}

exec('foo', 'a string')
// foo 42 a string
// foo 58 a string

exec('bar', 10101010)
// bar 42 10101010
// bar 58 10101010
```

Comment: I don't really need context binding, but the solution is the "as". Thanks!